# Subset of the same column

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame and I need to do a subset of different group of different columns so I use this script

```
a <- subset(table, Response=="oxygen" & Operation=="blue" & Group=="A")
```

My question is: I need to include in this subgroup also the rows of the group B ( I have in the data frame also other type of group (C, D, F).
I have tried to use this script but it doesn't work

```
a <- subset(table, Response=="oxygen" & Operation=="blue" & Group==c("A", "B"))
```

Could you tell me the correct syntax to use please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select both groups `A` & `B`, you need to use `%in%` instead of `==`:

```
a <- subset(table, Response=="oxygen" & Operation=="blue" & Group %in% c("A", "B"))
```